# Construction Heuristics on VRP - slow on large datasets

Tags: optaplanner

I have a large VRP problem with over 10,000 stops. Building out the construction heuristics takes a long time no matter what options are used including filters and other tricks.

The move and swap algorithms generally work well once they start, but it takes 30 mins to solve the construction phase.

Any suggestions for options that may provide a better outcome? I get the feeling that Optaplanner is being too strict at the construction phase, when a simpler option may be a better balance.

Config that seems to work the best is as follows:

```
<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <entitySelector id="placerEntitySelector">
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
            <sorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY</sorterManner>
        </entitySelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="placerEntitySelector" />
            <filterClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.solver.CustomerSelectionFilter</filterClass>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>
```

Cheers, nick

Comment: adding the following helped a lot, but it slows towards the end.<selectedCountLimit>1</selectedCountLimit>

Comment: So I have looked at this further. I noticed the following behaviourshe count limit needs to be greater than the number of vehicles otherwise vehicle 1 is always selected. This suggests that the CH approach is to always try to fill the first vehicle and

Comment: So I have looked at this further. I noticed the following behaviours.   1. count limit needs to be greater than the number of vehicles otherwise The vehicles above the count limit are never selected. This suggests that the CH approach is to always try to fill the first vehicle and then to successively work through each vehicle, even if they are already full.  3. The orders are filled according to highest latitude, which probably isn't ideal.  Filling by clusters / nearest neighbour or largest size would seem to make sense to me. Nick

Answer (score 0):

A couple of idea's that I did on non-VRP cases (which will work, to some degree):

- `selectedCountLimit` (I wouldn't go as low as 1 though) is indeed the standard way to speed up construction heuristics. Trade result quality for speed.
- The CH FIRST_FEASIBLE_FIT is another way. It's similar to selectedCountLimit 1. The difference is that it selects more values as long as it hasn't found a value yet that doesn't break any hard constraints.

The real solution, because you got 10k+ VRP locations:

- **Nearby selection inside Construction Heuristics** (I presume you're already using Nearby Selection inside Local Search (if not, you should be)). I haven't done any experiments with this yet - it's on my non-customer-priority todo list. I believe a few improvements are needed in optaplanner-core, but nothing big. The problems in 6.2: 1) CH require ending selectors and nearby selection is always never ending (because it uses probabilities). A combination of selectionOrder RANDOM and selectionLimit 1000 can probably deal with this. Or better yet, we should support original selection in nearby order (which would be ending and would not use probabilities). Note that selectionLimit in itself doesn't suffice because the "nearby" order of the entity list differs from entity to entity. 2) Certain nearby random distributions don't allow a chance to select every element. Only initialized elements must be selectable (other wise chaining principles are broken). Not sure what happens there now. Need to verify.
- The Construction Heuristic "Nearest Neighbor". Not yet implemented out-of-the-box in optaplanner 6.2. While (true) connect the 2 locations that are closest to each other. Might temporarily break chaining principles... It's the inverse of Fit First. Instead of fitting the entity's one by one (take an entity and find its value), the values are fit one by one (take a value and find its entity.

HTH

Comment: Thanks @GeoffreyDeSmet,

As per your suggestions:

- Using 250 is a good balance for selectedCountLimit. 250, which is about 50 above the number of vehicles seems to be a good option.
- I have applied the first feasible solution, but as I am using an initialising score trend of ONLY_DOWN, it doesn’t apply.
- Actually, I am still on 6.1 and will upgrade to 6.2 shortly. Certainly the improved VRP features will help, but I would look for this to improve upon a good CH solution.
- Nearest neighbour / greedy style algorithms are used on some of the commercial VRPs that can solve in <30 seconds.

Comment: Speaking of the commercial solvers, they seem to:
- Allocate vehicles across the locations, and build up solutions
- Fit largest orders first
- Accept initial feasible solutions early and then move on (as per your suggestion above)
- Prune impossible solutions (such as where two orders are in excess of the maximum vehicle capacity)
- Implement nearby selection heavily (as you suggested)

+ Concerned that adding street distances will only slow it down further.
My instance is built off the example in 6.1, which works remarkably well. Great job BTW.

Nick

Comment: [Upgrade to 6.2 and use Nearby Selection in Local Search. See this blog.](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/01/27/ScalingVehicleRoutingAndTSPWithNearbySelection.html)  The rest is just icing on the cake ;)